Некорректно отображается картинка в html


header {
    background-image: url("media/img/1.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div>
                <h1>Ecogo</h1>
                <!-- <img src="media/img/1.jpg"> -->
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>



Картинка в теге html отображается корректно, но стоит мне её переместить в css и всё ломается, она отрисовывается пропорционально введённому тексту, т.е. написал слово - отобразился кусочек картинки высотой с введённое слово, написал 2 строчки - отобразился фрагмент картинки высотой с две строчки. Мне нужно сразу вывести всю картинку целиком.
P.S. на форуме размещён похожий вопрос, те советы, которые там были предложены, я тоже пробовал

Ну так есть определенная разница, между тем когда Вы вешаете изображение на background и когда выводите через img тег, чтобы вывести всю картинку, то у блока должна быть определенная высота и ширина.

Мне нужно сделать изображение адаптивным. Я заранее не могу знать требуемую высоту блока

Тогда может быть на js это сделать?

@Ash ну и? Вы спросили, Вам ответили почему так, то как Вам бы хотелось, это уже другой вопрос. Почитайте про background-size и другие свойства фоновых изображений, сам блок вполне может быть адаптивным, иметь минимальную высоту и так далее.

Я описал свою проблему и сказал, что мне нужно отрисовать картинку полностью через css (про css понятно по контексту). На мой вопрос до сих пор не ответили, и моя проблема до сих пор не решена

Также, я уже пробовал сделать сам блок адаптивным. У меня не получилось, поэтому я и пришел на форум

@Ash "картинку полностью через css" -- полностью и в соответствии с ее реальным размером -- это разные вещи, так-то можно использовать и background-size: contain; и она будет выведена полностью, но просто ее высота будет равна высоте контента внутри контейнера (в Вашем случае два параграфа). В обычных условиях, CSS предполагает, что размеры фонового изображения должны каким-то образом коррелировать с размерами элемента, которому оно присвоено. Если размеры этого элемента не заданы, то и размеры фонового изображения будут автоматически адаптированы.
